# Xamarin - CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync saves 2 photo's in different locations

Tags: android, xamarin, android-7.0-nougat

I have created an app that takes pictures using Xamarins CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync

It's working almost perfectly but I can not stop it storing the same image twice.

This is how I create a image:

```
var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
                {
                    PhotoSize = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PhotoSize.Medium,
                    RotateImage = true,
                    AllowCropping = true,
                    Name = "photo1.jpg",
                    SaveToAlbum = false, 
                    DefaultCamera = CameraDevice.Rear, 

                });
```

This stores an image here:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/XamarinCamera.XamarinCamera/files/Pictures/photo1.jpg
```

But also saves one in the gallery too with

```
\Internal shared storage\DCIM\Camera\IMG_20200123_162022.jpg
```

How can I delete the 2nd image programmatically as soon as it's stored the 1st image?

I intend to delete both in the end but I need only the 1st image until the user has completed a couple more steps.

**file.Path;** only returns the first path so I only know the 2nd path once I've looked through the folder.

I'm using Android 7.0

I can't replicate this on my S10 which is using Android 9.0 (that **doesn't** store the image in the gallery.)

**** Edit ****

I've also tried to replicate the 2nd file name with

```
"IMG_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss") + ".jpg";
```

But this doesn't work because the user has to press OK or Retry after taking the image so if they wait for a second or press retry I've created the wrong file name.

**** Edit 2 ****

I've tried to make it store to the album and get the path from there but now it's saving in 3 directories xD. From my code I can only set / get the filename photo1 which is what I set. I need to know the 2nd image filename so I can then delete it.

Here's the 1st:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/XamarinCamera.XamarinCamera/files/Pictures/photo1.jpg
```

Here the 2nd:

```
/Internal shared storage/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20200123_165130.jpg
```

Here the 3rd:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/temp/photo1.jpg
```

Comment: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/issues/89

Comment: Ryan, as Jason showed above, it seems to be an issue in the library that you are using. You would have to find another library or implement the functionality yourself. There's even a $2 bounty on fixing that bug lol. One way you can find a fix, is to download the library and manually load it through VS instead of using it as a nuget, and then step through the code and check where's it's making the duplicate

Comment: It's a bit late but I resolved the issue and it wasn't the library (although it could be a bug with that library on the android I was using) I was testing using an old android device (not sure on the OS) but I copied the app onto my Samsung S10 and it now just takes 1 image. (this fixed it for me as the old device was just a testing one - in production everyone has a new device)